# "En voilà une qui"

Tags: sens

I think I understand the basic meaning of "En voilà une qui", but in this sentence I have difficulty understanding the meaning of the sentence.

> En voilà une qui a toujours fini sa soupe !

Comment: So far, what do you believe it means?

Answer (score 3):

"Here is one that always finishes her soup"

Literally, "here is one that has always finished her soup", so why wouldn't she finish it again ?

Basically, "en voilà une/un" is used to point somebody out.

Answer (score 2):

Take her as an example ! Her exists. We found her :
En voilà une qui...
This is not obvious. We respect her for that !
A toujours fini sa soupe
 She has always ended her job. She never went back. Never made faces. Reliable.